Checkbox with a third option: "partial", displayed as a dash in a box
I'm building a MacOS app using SwiftUI. I need it to allow the user to select an arbitrary number of options using checkboxes.
The options are grouped under category headings. Often when I see MacOS apps doing this—such as when an install is asking which files to install—each category has a three-state checkbox reflecting whether the category's options are selected:

[✓] All selected
[-] Some selected
[ ] None selected

Clicking the box next to the category chooses All or None, whereas the Some state arises when the user selects some but not all of the individual options within the category.
I've seen this used frequently in MacOS apps, but I have not seen the feature in SwiftUI. Is there an official way to do this? Or do I need to implement my own using, say, the SF Symbols checkmark.square, minus.square and square?

Apparently you need to set the allowsMixedState property on the button.

Thank you @jasonharper. I guess it's an AppKit thing, and I'm working in SwiftUI. Good to know about, though.

This is where you should use the Toggle initialisers that take a sources parameter, like init(sources:isOn:label:). The idea is, you give it a collection of things, as well as a Bool key path from each of the elements. The Toggle will decide what state it should be, depending on the key path's values.
Here is a complete example, adapted from the documentation:
struct Alarm: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var isOn = false
    var name = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var alarms = [
        Alarm(isOn: true, name: "Morning"),
        Alarm(isOn: false, name: "Evening")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        // this toggle will have a mixed state...
        Toggle(sources: $alarms, isOn: \.isOn) {
            Text("Enable all alarms")
        }

        // ... if only one of these toggles are toggled.
        ForEach($alarms) { $alarm in
            Toggle(alarm.name, isOn: $alarm.isOn)
        }
    }
}


Outrageous! It not only gives the "partial" checkbox I was looking for… but it does it automatically, and even lays it out with indents. Frankly, I wasn't very hopeful, but this nails it! Thank you, @Sweeper!

If you're developing for a Mac, check out allowsMixedState. Instead of using a Toggle (inherently two-state), you can use a NSButton as a checkbox. You can then set it to the intermediate state using setNextState().
Also, iOS doesn't support this natively, but RVS_Checkbox can add support.

Thank you, Camdan - that's great to know about. I guess I didn't encounter it because I'm using SwiftUI - in fact, I've never used AppKit  so I'd have to learn how to integrate that into SwiftUI. Hmm…

To the best of my knowledge, there's no native way to implement an intermediate checkbox in SwiftUI. I also don't see them super often anymore, so I wouldn't expect there to be great support these days. I've done a little searching, and it doesn't seem like there's tons of resources. We'll see if anyone else shares there 2 cents.

What do you know! Check out @Sweeper's solution. :)

Wonderful! If it worked, make sure you mark that as the accepted solution.
